# SQL Server : export several databases schemas

Tags: sql-server, export, database-schema

I've found the question about how to export a database schema to a script has been asked and answered here already, but I have a scenario of a database server that contains almost 200 databases so right clicking on each one of them to generate scripts for every single one is not practical.

I'd like to know if there is a more elegant option to achieve this.

I want to be able to save the schemas only, of the whole server structure and their databases.
I can think of a script that could first get a list of databases and then iterate through each one of them and exporting the schemas of all of them, but I don't really know how to achieve this!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

http://www.nigelrivett.net/DMOScriptAllDatabases.html

You can automate this using DMO, although I have no sample script for you.